# Django Dynamically search item by month using datepicker

Tags: jquery, python, django, datepicker

i am novice in Django.I am developing a project using Django.My project is relevant to image.In my project i want to add a date picker by which user can search his uploaded image by per month.

Just for example,if a user select January month of any year from a date picker to see his uploaded images, he will provided those images which is uploaded in the month of January of that year.Now how can i do this using Django. For better convenience i am providing the model,forms and views  which is related to upload images.

here is the models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    approved_by = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField('date downloaded',auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def UserImageUpload(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your Image upload is waiting for Admin approval')

            newdoc = Photo(photo =  request.FILES['photo'],user = request.user,name = request.POST['name'],uploaded_time=datetime.datetime.now())
            newdoc.save()
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Something is Missing!')

        else:
            form = DocumentForm()

        uploaded_image = Photo.objects.all()

        return render_to_response('myprofile/user_image_upload.html',{'uploaded_image':uploaded_image,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and form.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.CharField(label='Name Of Your Image',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control',}))
        photo = forms.ImageField(
                      label='Select a file',)
```

You can use any example  templates to use Date picker and show the search results.

Comment: in fact i need some examples here,i don't need straight forward answers.If you have any,then share with me.

Comment: Examples are found by googling. You could start there. It's your job to dig up the examples not ask for them here. Asking for examples here, that you could find yourself on google is still asking others to do your job for yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask at First point - Search and research.

Comment: @Tanweer "I don't need straight forward answers." But that's what this site is for; clear, detailed answers to specific, practical programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example.

Form for validating date input:

```
class PickDateForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'any_custom_class_name'}))
```

View:

```
def query_by_month(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PickDateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            selected_date= form.cleaned_data['date']    # 'selected_date' is a datetime.date object
            photos = Photo.objects.filter(uploaded_time__year=selected_date.year,
                                          uploaded_time__month=selected_date.month)
            return HttpResponse('Photos: ' + repr(photos))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid form')
    else:
        form = PickDateForm()
    return render(request, 'pickdate.html', {'form': form})
```

The HTML (using [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".any_custom_class_name" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/pick_date/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```